# Is there a way to improve the performance of downloading files from Minio?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs, minio

I'm currently using K6 to load test my API that sends a download request to Minio.  The load test is set to have a maximum of 200 VUs, but the ramp up to the max number of VUs takes about 15 minutes.  But besides that, this is the logic I have for fetching a 70MB file from Minio.  Everything is written with NestJS.

```js
@Injectable()
export class S3Service {
 private readonly s3ClientCache: Map<string, S3> = new Map();

 async getS3Client() {
    const endpoint = this.configService.get('s3.endpoint');

    if (!this.s3ClientCache.has(endpoint)) {
      const s3 = new S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        forcePathStyle: true,
        tls: false,
        region: 'us-west-1',
        endpoint: this.configService.get('s3.endpoint'),
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: this.configService.get('s3.accessKey'),
          secretAccessKey: this.configService.get('s3.secretKey'),
        },
      });
      this.s3ClientCache.set(endpoint, s3);
    }

    return this.s3ClientCache.get(endpoint);
  }

 async downloadObject(s3Path: string) {
    const s3Client = await this.getS3Client();

    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: 'test',
      Key: s3Path,
    });

    try {
      const response = await s3Client.send(command);
      const inputStream = response.Body;
      const downloadPath = `./test_objects/${basename(s3Path)}`;
      const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath);

      if (inputStream instanceof Readable) {
        inputStream.pipe(outputStream);
      }
      outputStream.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('File downloaded successfully');
        return HttpStatus.CREATED;
      });
      outputStream.on('error', function () {
        console.log('Error downloading file');
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the issue I'm having is that when I reach around 50+ VUs, response time will be around 1-3 minutes, which is expected. I always thought that these download requests would be handled in parallel, but I'm not sure.  So I'm trying to figure out some way to improve the performance by modifying the logic, though this could also be a hardware issue as well (e.g. server internet speed).  Any advice on this would be much appreciated!  Here is a graph if you're curious on what the data looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAQ9l.png)

Comment: What is a "VU"? Is it something in Minio? If you want to see what might be possible, you could try using the AWS CLI against Minio. It performs copies in parallel (eg using `aws s3 sync`), so it would give you an indication of what speed might be possible.

Comment: VU stands for "virtual users."  It's a term coined by k6 (https://k6.io/docs/get-started/running-k6/).  It's a JavaScript library for load testing application.